# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: php, javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

I have code of file upload in my site in JS:

```
function detectDone(){
done++;
var _ifrWallp = document.getElementById("ifrWallp");
var html = _ifrWallp.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
if (html.indexOf('File name:') != -1) {
    // Done
    uploadedWall();
} else {
    setTimeout('detectDone()',10);
}}
```

and HTML:

```
<div id="addWallpp" class="addMWallp" style="float: left;" onmouseover="document.getElementById('uploadDesc').style.display = 'block'; document.getElementById('ifrWallp').contentWindow.document.getElementById('wpmain').style.backgroundColor = '#FFF7C0';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('uploadDesc').style.display = 'none'; document.getElementById('ifrWallp').contentWindow.document.getElementById('wpmain').style.backgroundColor = '#F9F9F9';">
    <iframe id="ifrWallp" onload="Upload('../')" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;border-style:none;margin:0px;width:100%;height:45px" src="sources/private/upload.php"></iframe>
```

and some code in php file.
In IE i have no error but chrome and firefox give error in line:

```
var html = _ifrWallp.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

and in FF:

TypeError: _ifrWall.contentWindow.document.body is null

I know that I have to load iframe code after the page was loaded but unfortunately I do not know how to do it to make it work with my file upload. Please help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the explanation and a code sample here:
http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?405244-InnerHTML-and-Firefox

Basically contentWindow is an IE thing. For FF you need to use contentDocument.

```
//ff
if (_ifrWallp.contentDocument){
var html=_ifrWallp.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].innerHTML;
}
//ie
else if (_ifrWallp.contentWindow){
var html=_ifrWallp.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
 }

// if (html.indexOf('File name:') ... etc
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but now I have error in FF>>>>>> TypeError: _ifrWallp.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName(...)[0]                   and in chrome>>>>>>>>>       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined  :((

Comment: Ok I setTimeout to '100' and everything works perfect now :) Thanks DmitryK

Comment: @user2758990 Why use setTimeout instead of just listening for a load event on the iframe?